# Change only the DataValueField of a Listbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a `Listbox`

```
dimension.DataSource = provider.DimensionList;
dimension.DataBind();
```

I want the value to be the `ID` of these elements

```
dimension.DataSource = provider.DimensionList;
dimension.DataValueField = "ID";
dimension.DataBind();
```

But I don't want the text to change to the `ID`, I want that the `dimension.DataTextField` gets the `object.ToString()`.

How can this be done?

Comment: The answer given by maus is pretty cool. But just curious, is your Listbox's DataTextField set to ID if you don't specify anything? By default it should be set to item.ToString() [Item in DimensionList] and you could override the ToString() method in item's type which should solve your issue.

Comment: @Vijay, I don't specify anything. I tried to set it to empty and null but nothing changed. I guess if one is set, both gets the value...

Comment: Could you try overriding the ToString() method on the DimensionList's item's type and see what happens. ex: if each item in DimensionList is of type Test class, you could provide ToString() method in Test to return a string representation of the current state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly the type of the DimensionList, but I believe that you could use a select that will return an anonymous type:

```
dimension.DataSource = provider.DimensionList.Select(d=>new {Id=d.Id,Text=d.ToString()}).ToList();
dimension.DataValueField = "Id";
dimension.DataTextField = "Text";
dimension.DataBind();
```